# Drag and drop in Tauri + Yew

Tags: rust, tauri, yew

I am having issues with handling [drag and drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop). I `prevent_default` on my drop target for both the `dragEnter` and `dragOver` events, which I can verify are firing, but the `drop` event is never triggered. I have also tried setting the `dataTransfer.dropEffect` property, which has no effect.

```rust
use yew::prelude::*;
use web_sys::{DragEvent, console::log_1};

#[function_component(App)]
pub fn app() -> Html {
    let ondragenter = Callback::from(|e: DragEvent| {
        e.prevent_default();
        e.data_transfer().unwrap().set_drop_effect("move"); // optional
        log_1(&"enter".into());
    });

    let ondragover = Callback::from(|e: DragEvent| {
        e.prevent_default();
        log_1(&"over".into());
    });

    let ondrop = Callback::from(|e: DragEvent| {
        log_1(&"drop".into());
    });

    html! {
        <main style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;"
            {ondragenter}
            {ondragover}
            {ondrop}>
        </main>
    }
}
```

with `web_sys`'s [`DragEvent`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.DragEvent.html) and [`DataTransfer`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.DataTransfer.html) features enabled.

I am running this using [Tauri](https://tauri.app/) and have tried with [Yew](https://yew.rs/) v. `0.19` and `0.20`.

Comment: What exactly are you dropping onto that component? Is it a file? Have you tried dropping something else?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Yes, for files. Indeed, the `drop` event is triggered when dropping text from the same `window`.

Comment: It also appears that the code functions correctly in Brave browser, so perhAps this is an issue with Tauri.

Comment: Here are some issues with discussions around this issue: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/2768, https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/discussions/4736